# Last tennis players to win Grand Slam on home soil

Tags: trivia, tennis, atp, wta, grand-slam

Who are the last male and female singles' tennis players to win a grand slam on home soil?

In other words, which male and female Australian, French, British and American athletes most recently won the Australian Open, the French Open, the Wimbledon, and the US open respectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of end 2022 US Open this is the list of last tennis players who won grand slam championships on home soil:

**Men's**:

- [Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Australian_Open_men%27s_singles_champions): Mark Edmondson - 1976
- [French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_Open_men%27s_singles_champions): Yannick Noah - 1983
- [Wimbledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wimbledon_gentlemen%27s_singles_champions): Andy Murray - 2016
- [US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_US_Open_men%27s_singles_champions): Andy Roddick - 2003

**Women's**:

- [Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Australian_Open_women%27s_singles_champions): Ashleigh Barty - 2022
- [French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_Open_women%27s_singles_champions): Mary Pierce - 2000
- [Wimbledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wimbledon_ladies%27_singles_champions): Virginia Wade - 1977
- [US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_US_Open_women%27s_singles_champions): Sloane Stephens - 2017